# $I_{2n}=\dfrac{1\times 3\times \ldots \times (2n-1)}{2\times 4\times \ldots\times 2n}\times\dfrac{\pi}{2}\quad \forall n\geq 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, contest-math

> let  $$I_n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n(t) \, dt$$
>
> show that
>
> $$I_{2n}=\frac{1\times 3\times \ldots \times (2n-1)}{2\times 4\times \ldots\times 2n}\times\dfrac{\pi}{2}\quad \forall n\geq 1$$

My attempts :

by using integration by parts we can get : 
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\quad (2n)I_{2n}=(2n-1)I_{2n-2}$$
$$I_{2n}=\frac{(2n-1)}{2n}I_{2n-2}$$

Answer (score 1):

For $n\ge 2$,

$$\begin{align}
I_n&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n}xdx\\
&=\cos^{n-1} x\sin x|_{x=0}^{\pi/2}+(n-1)\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2x\cos^{n-2}xdx\\
&=(n-1)(I_{n-2}-I_n)
\end{align}$$

Therefore,
$$I_n=\frac{n-1}nI_{n-2}$$

Now,
$$I_0=\int_0^{\pi/2}dx=\frac\pi2$$
and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way. However the relation should be $\;I_{2n}=\dfrac{2n-1}{2n} I_{2n-2}$.

Then write this relation for decrasing values of n, until $I_2=\dfrac12 I_0$, compute $I_0$, and multiply all the equalities.

Answer (score 0):

[Here you have all you need !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals)

I love when Feynman use them !